C++ function parameter overload with parent-child arguments
I am working on a C++ project involving class inheritance and function parameter overloading. I have two base classes that should never be instantiated but only inherited (by design choice):
#include <iostream>

class Item {
public:
    virtual void use() = 0;
};
class ItemSword : public Item {
public:
    void use() override {}
};
class ItemPickaxe : public Item {
public:
    void use() override {}
};

class Evaluator {
public:
    void val(Item& item) {
        std::cout << "get_val default, item type: " << typeid(item).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

class EvaluatorZombie : public Evaluator {
public:
    void val(ItemPickaxe& item) {
        std::cout << "get_val zombie, item type: " << typeid(item).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Evaluator evaluator = EvaluatorZombie();


    auto item1 = ItemSword();
    evaluator.val(item1);   // "get_val default, item type: 9ItemSword"

    auto item2 = ItemPickaxe();
    evaluator.val(item2);   // "get_val default, item type: 11ItemPickaxe", 
                            //but I want "get_val zombie, item type: 11ItemPickaxe"
}


I essentially want the .val(ItemType) call to first check if ItemType exists in the evaluator, and if it doesn't, then use the parent .val(Item). Where ItemType inherits from Item.
The specific item "type" may be different and is not known at compile time, so I realize this may be an issue.
All the solutions I have seen require either implementing all "items" in a single "get_val" method in the Evaluators, but I want to be able to implement multiple "get_vals" for different items in the Evaluator children classes, and then use a default when an Item is not implemented in a get_val.
So I want a solution that:

Allows me to write multiple get_vals in the Evaluator children for each Item class
Does not modify the original "Item" and "Evaluator", or at least does it to a minimum. I want the original "Item" and "Evaluator" to be agnostic to the children.

Any help or thoughts is appreciated, thank you.

You should be able to add using base_class_name:function_name; to the derived class to import the base class function into the derived class.

The derived class currently does import the base class method. So in the example, if I was to write evaluatorZombie.get_val(std::make_unique), it will correctly use the default method from the parent Evaluator class, as that is the default implementation. The issue is when I use ItemSword, I want it to use the method in the child class. But they both use the default method.
Thank you for any help.

Can you make an [mre]?  The code you say you are using doesn't match the code you've shown.

Yes I will do it now. Sorry for the inconvenience!

An option is that EvaluatorZombie inherits from Evaluator publicly but Evaluator has a protected destructor.

"should never be instantiated" - As a design rule or by making it impossible? Right now, nothing prevents instantiating those base classes except if you have  documentation that says "don't". I'll wait for the [mre] before looking more closely at this.

The code shown has many issues. It doesn't compile. No virtuals in the base classes, especially the destructors. No "pure" virtual methods or private constructors to prevent instantiating the base classes. Both get_val() methods are private. Evaluator::get_val() suffers from object slicing. Private inheritance being used to inherit the base classes. std::make_unique<ItemSword> item in a function call is bad syntax. You can't pass a unique_ptr where a ItemSword& reference is expected. No need to use unique_ptr in this example. Please fix the code so it at least compiles.

I have fixed the original question, so that it at the very least is runnable. @TedLyngmo it is a design choice, basically the user should create their own "Item" types and "Evaluator"s, and then the val can be used as default if the user doesn't implement their own.

UPDATE:
In your updated example, evaluator.val(item2) does not call EvaluatorZombie::val() like you want, because evaluator is not declared as an EvaluatorZombie to begin with.  You are "slicing" the EvaluatorZombie object into a base Evaluator object, which is why Evaluator::val() is being called.
What is object slicing?
You would need to change the declaration of evaluator to be an EvaluatorZombie object without slicing it, eg:
auto evaluator = EvaluatorZombie();
// or simply:
EvaluatorZombie evaluator;

You would also need to expose access to the Evaluator::val method in EvaluatorZombie, such as with a using statement, otherwise EvaluatorZombie::val will hide Evaluator::val and you will get a compile error trying to pass anything other than an ItemPickaxe to EvaluatorZombie::val():
class EvaluatorZombie : public Evaluator {
public:
    using Evaluator::val; // <-- ADD THIS

    void val(ItemPickaxe& item) {
        std::cout << "get_val zombie, item type: " << typeid(item).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

Or, declare evaluator as an Evaluator* (or std::unique_ptr<Evaluator>) pointer.  Polymorphic method dispatch only works via pointers and references.
That being said...

(original answer)
Make Evaluator::get_val() be virtual so EvaluatorZombie can override it, and then use dynamic_cast to test if the passed Item is a specific derived type.
For example:
class Item {
public:
    virtual ~Item() = default;
};

class Evaluator {
public:
    virtual ~Evaluator() = default;
    virtual int get_val(const Item& item) {
        // use item as needed...
        return ...;
    }
};

class ItemSword : public Item {};
class ItemPickaxe : public Item {};

class EvaluatorZombie : public Evaluator {
public:
    int get_val(const ItemSword& sword) {
        // use sword as needed...
        return ...;
    }

    int get_val(const Item& item) override {
        const ItemSword *sword = dynamic_cast<const ItemSword*>(&item);
        if (sword)
            return get_val(*sword);

        return Evaluator::get_val(item);
    }
};

// calls EvaluatorZombie::get_val(const ItemSword&)
EvaluatorZombie{}.get_val(ItemSword{});

// calls EvaluatorZombie::get_val(const Item&)
// which calls Evaluator::get_val(const Item&)
EvaluatorZombie{}.get_val(ItemPickaxe{});

Online Demo

UPDATE:
Another option is to have each Evaluator descendant register the types it is interested in, and then have get_val() lookup the passed Item in the registered data to know what it do next with it, eg:
class Item {
public:
    virtual std::string Type() const { return "Item"; }
    virtual ~Item() = default;
};

class Evaluator {
protected:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<int(const Item&)>> get_val_funcs;

public:
    virtual ~Evaluator() = default;

    int get_val(const Item& item) {
        auto iter = get_val_funcs.find(item.Type());
        if (iter != get_val_funcs.end()) {
            return iter->second(item);
        }
        return ...;
    }
};

class ItemSword : public Item {
public:
    std::string Type() const override { return "Sword"; }
};

class ItemPickaxe : public Item {
public:
    std::string Type() const override { return "Pickaxe"; }
};

class EvaluatorZombie : public Evaluator {
public:
    EvaluatorZombie() {
        get_val_funcs["Sword"] = [this](const Item& item){
            return get_val(static_cast<const ItemSword&>(item));
        };
    }

    int get_val(const ItemSword& item) {
        // use sword as needed...
        return ...;
    }
};

// calls EvaluatorZombie::get_val(const ItemSword&)
EvaluatorZombie{}.get_val(ItemSword{});

// calls EvaluatorZombie::get_val(const Item&)
// which calls Evaluator::get_val(const Item&)
EvaluatorZombie{}.get_val(ItemPickaxe{});

// calls Evaluator::get_val(const Item&)
// which calls EvaluatorZombie::get_val(const ItemSword&)
EvaluatorZombie evaluator;
Evaluator &eval_ref = evaluator;
eval_ref.get_val(ItemSword{});
Evaluator *eval_ptr = &evaluator;
eval_ptr->get_val(ItemSword{});

Online Demo

Firstly, thank you for the suggestion, and sorry for the question being a mess. Although this works, it potentially requires a long if-else, if there are many Item types and it requires it for each Evaluator".." that is implemented. Is there a way to do this where we avoid that? Thank you

Or even if there is a way to do it where you add code to Item/Evaluator classes (that don't reference the child classes directly.

Unless you have tons of items per Evaluator, an if-else chain is really not that bad. But, if you really want to avoid that, then you need a runtime registration system, where each Evaluator registers the types it is interested in, and then val() can lookup the passed object type in the registered types to figure out what to invoke next. Or, change val() to call a virtual method on Item, and then have each Item override that method to do something depending on which Evaluator is calling it. The whole point of polymorphism is to NOT have to care which type an object is.

thank you very much. As you mentioned, it seems that the using Evaluator::val; is what I needed. This works in the minimal reproducible example but does not work for my larger project (for whatever reason). But I will accept the answer and return to debugging. Thank you :)

So my problem stems from that I need std::vector<Evaluator> evaluators that can contain different types of evaluators. Then when I do evaluators[0]->val(item1) it uses the default val in both cases. Here is an example: Online Demo is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

std::vector<Evaluator> will slice any derived objects. As I said in my answer, you MUST use pointers in this case for polymorphism to work properly (you can't use references with std::vector) , so use either std::vector<Evaluator*> or better std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Evaluator>>

I believe that is what I am doing, if you check the demo I use std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Evaluator>>, and then push std::make_unique<EvaluatorZombie>. But it seems it is still sliced?

@AhmadOthman no, it did not slice. The problem is that you are calling val() via a base Evaluator* pointer and Evaluator::val()is not virtual, so it cannot call EvaluatorZombie::val(). I already showed you how to make this work. Go look at my examples again more carefully.
